# Rails: Calling API (another domain) to get search results

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm having trouble with a pretty simple flow in Rails. I want to have a user type in some text and then call the backend which will then make a GET request to a RESTful API in another domain. I then want to use this information to display the search results but I don't have access to the variable I set for some reason.

houses_controller.rb

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

    def search
        @search_results = ["fake", "test", "results"]
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/houses/search", method: "get", remote: true) do %>
    <%= label_tag(:query, "Search for:") %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<% if(@search_results.nil?) %>
  <p>nil....</p>
<% else %>
    <% @search_results.each do |res| %>
      <p>
        "result..."
      </p> 
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root :to => "houses#index"
  get "/houses/search" => "houses#search"
end
```

I start on the root page and I used `remote: true` in my form_tag because I believe this is how people do AJAX requests? Am I completely off to do an ajax request this way with rails? I would prefer to just use jquery but it seemed like this was the Rails way to do it.

I also tried having a search.html.erb because I saw a message while debugging that read `"No template found for HousesController#search, rendering head :no_content"` but even when I added that file, it didn't make a difference because it was still rendering the index.html.erb file and completely ignoring the search.html.erb file.

I also tried setting `@search_results` in the index action. It works if I set it in there but I don't want the static value that I would set in there, I want the value that is generated when I call the 'search' action.

Answer (score 0):

If you use remote: true you should create a search.js.erb not html.erb. You could use a respond_to block and specify the behaviour for js call.